# Resource Not Found Crash. The project doesn't contain references to design_ic_visibility file at all

Tags: android, crash, resources, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

My app has encountered a crash on some devices with `ResourcesNotFoundException`. 
My test devices don't have such a problem, the devices that suffer the crash are Pixel 1 and Nexus 5X.

The resource ID in the message from the crash log points to `design_ic_visibility` and I've found it in my R file. I don't have that resource in my project, so my best bet is that it comes from some lirary.

The following lines are the long i'm referring to:

```
androidx.core.content.a.c()
EXCEPTION
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
MESSAGE
Unable to find resource ID #0x7f08009b
```

**EDIT**: 
Thanks to @Mike M. we determined it is the resource for password toggle and after looking into the event trail it does look like it.

**I would appreciate an immediate solution if possible. I already submitted this info to google issue tracker but need to resolve the crash now**

Event trail:

```
  android....rcesImpl   
ResourcesImpl.java line 228 in android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName()
android....rcesImpl 
ResourcesImpl.java line 687 in android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie()
android....rcesImpl 
ResourcesImpl.java line 571 in android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable()
android....esources 
Resources.java line 858 in android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable()
android....pedArray 
TypedArray.java line 928 in android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable()
android....pedArray 
XResources.java line 1363 in android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getDrawable()
android....Drawable 
AnimatedStateListDrawable.java line 504 in android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.parseItem()
android....Drawable 
AnimatedStateListDrawable.java line 453 in android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflateChildElements()
android....Drawable 
AnimatedStateListDrawable.java line 385 in android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflate()
android....Inflater 
DrawableInflater.java line 130 in android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml()
android....Drawable 
Drawable.java line 1227 in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner()
android....Drawable 
Drawable.java line 1200 in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml()
android....rcesImpl 
ResourcesImpl.java line 715 in android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie()
android....rcesImpl 
ResourcesImpl.java line 571 in android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable()
android....esources 
Resources.java line 771 in android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable()
android....esources 
XResources.java line 790 in android.content.res.XResources.getDrawable()
android.....Context 
Context.java line 525 in android.content.Context.getDrawable()
androidx...ontent.a 
line 2 in androidx.core.content.a.c()
androidx...idget.l0 
line 15 in androidx.appcompat.widget.l0.a()
androidx...idget.l0 
line 11 in androidx.appcompat.widget.l0.a()
a.a.k.a.a   
line 1 in a.a.k.a.a.c()
com.goog...Delegate 
line 2 in com.google.android.material.textfield.PasswordToggleEndIconDelegate.initialize()
com.goog...utLayout 
line 5 in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.setEndIconMode()
com.goog...utLayout 
line 184 in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>()
```

Comment: If you're using Material Components, that's the eye icon for `TextInputLayout`; e.g., this one: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/drawable-anydpi-v21/design_ic_visibility.xml.

Comment: I am using this component and material components library, but after looking at their folders it does look like this folder contains this resource (drawable-anydpi-v21). Do u know why this resource could be not found in my project?

Comment: Not really, off the top of my head. I assume it works on other 21+ devices?

Comment: these are the OS versions from that crash log (8.0.0, 7.1.1, 9, 6.0.1) So even 9 and 8, I created an emulator for Nexus 5X device and it does show this icon so may it be it is coming from a different library, is there a way to determine from which package the resource was merged?